# add mapping to C++ lambda from LLVM

Tags: c++, lambda, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I have a set of lambdas that wrap a C++ method call and I want to call these with LLVM. My attempt seems to be missing something, even after declaring the type and adding a global mapping to the lambda, I get an LLVM error. The minimal code to reproduce what I tried is:

```
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/GenericValue.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/Interpreter.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Constants.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/Support/ManagedStatic.h"
#include "llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h"

using namespace llvm;

int main() {

  InitializeNativeTarget();

  LLVMContext Context;

  std::unique_ptr<Module> Owner = make_unique<Module>("SomeModule", Context);
  Module *M = Owner.get();

  FunctionType *lambdaFT = FunctionType::get(Type::getInt32Ty(Context), false);
  Function *lambdaFN = Function::Create(lambdaFT, Function::ExternalLinkage, "lambda", Owner.get());
  //this is what the original question had
  //auto lambdaBody = []() { return 100; };
  //this is an edit after Johannes Schaub's answer
  int32_t ( *lambdaBody)() = +[]() { return 100; };

  Function *mainF = cast<Function>(M->getOrInsertFunction("main", Type::getInt32Ty(Context), (Type *) 0));

  BasicBlock *BB = BasicBlock::Create(Context, "EntryBlock", mainF);
  IRBuilder<> builder(BB);

  CallInst *lambdaRes = builder.CreateCall(lambdaFN, std::vector<Value *>(), "lambdaRetVar");
  builder.CreateRet(lambdaRes);

  ExecutionEngine *EE = EngineBuilder(std::move(Owner)).create();
  EE->addGlobalMapping(lambdaFN, &lambdaBody);

  outs() << "We just constructed this LLVM module:\n\n" << *M;
  outs() << "\n\nRunning main: ";

  std::vector<GenericValue> noargs;
  GenericValue gv = EE->runFunction(mainF, noargs);

  outs() << "Result: " << gv.IntVal << "\n";
  llvm_shutdown();
  delete EE;
  return 0;
}
```

This results in the output:

```
We just constructed this LLVM module:

; ModuleID = 'SomeModule'

declare i32 @lambda()

define i32 @main() {
EntryBlock:
  %lambdaRetVar = call i32 @lambda()
  ret i32 %lambdaRetVar
}

Running main: 
LLVM ERROR: Tried to execute an unknown external function: lambda
```

What am I doing wrong?
Using LLVM `3.7.0` (tag doesn't exist)

Comment: You are missing an information: Where and how have you defined "lambda"?

Comment: My intention is to link to the lambda defined as `auto lambdaBody = []() { return 100; };` in the code sample. In my actual code, the lambdas are member variables of a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda body is a class. You must pass the address of its function call operator, which you can do by converting it to a function pointer: `auto lambdaBody = +[]() { return 100; };` and passing it as a `void*`: `EE->addGlobalMapping(lambdaFN, reinterpret_cast<void*>(lambdaBody));`.

Comment: ok, makes sense (lambdas get converted to a struct right?), but doing that still give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

`Johannes Schaub`'s answer about lambda helped but it turns out `addGlobalMapping` doesn't do what I thought. There were a few things missing as well.
Most importantly:

```
EE->InstallLazyFunctionCreator([&](const std::string &fnName) -> void * {
    if (fnName == "lambda") { return reinterpret_cast<void *>(lambdaBody); }
    return nullptr;
  });
```

`InstallLazyFunctionCreator` is used when a function cannot be resolved. It gets called with the name of the function and in response, this function returns `nullptr` if not found or the function to be executed.

Here's the full code listing, with some additions (not all required):

```
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/GenericValue.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/Interpreter.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/RTDyldMemoryManager.h"
//must include to avoid "JIT has not been linked in" when creating the ExecutionEngine - https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22910
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/MCJIT.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Constants.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/Support/ManagedStatic.h"
#include "llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace llvm;

int proxy() { return 1000; }

int main() {

  InitializeNativeTarget();
  llvm::InitializeNativeTargetAsmPrinter();
  llvm::InitializeNativeTargetAsmParser();

  LLVMContext Context;

  std::unique_ptr<Module> Owner = make_unique<Module>("SomeModule", Context);
  Module *M = Owner.get();

  FunctionType *lambdaFT = FunctionType::get(Type::getInt32Ty(Context), false);
  Function *lambdaFN = Function::Create(lambdaFT, Function::ExternalLinkage, "lambda", Owner.get());
  int32_t ( *lambdaBody)() = +[]() { return 9099899; };

  assert(9099899 == lambdaBody()); //make sure we can call it
  Function *mainF = cast<Function>(M->getOrInsertFunction("main", Type::getInt32Ty(Context), (Type *) 0));

  BasicBlock *BB = BasicBlock::Create(Context, "EntryBlock", mainF);
  IRBuilder<> builder(BB);

  CallInst *lambdaRes = builder.CreateCall(lambdaFN, std::vector<Value *>(), "lambdaRetVar");
  builder.CreateRet(lambdaRes);
  EngineBuilder eb(std::move(Owner));
  std::unique_ptr<RTDyldMemoryManager> MM;
  std::string Error;
  ExecutionEngine *EE = eb.setEngineKind(EngineKind::JIT)
                          .setMCJITMemoryManager(std::move(MM))
                          .setErrorStr(&Error)
                          .setOptLevel(CodeGenOpt::None)
                          .setCodeModel(CodeModel::JITDefault)
                          .setRelocationModel(Reloc::Default)
                              //.setMArch(MArch)
                          .setMCPU(sys::getHostCPUName())
                              //.setMAttrs(MAttrs)
                          .create();
  std::cout << Error << std::endl;
  EE->InstallLazyFunctionCreator([&](const std::string &fnName) -> void * {
    if (fnName == "lambda") { return reinterpret_cast<void *>(lambdaBody); }
    return nullptr;
  });
  EE->finalizeObject();
  outs() << "We just constructed this LLVM module:\n\n" << *M;
  outs() << "\n\nRunning main: ";

  std::vector<GenericValue> noargs;
  GenericValue gv = EE->runFunction(mainF, noargs);

  outs() << "Result: " << gv.IntVal << "\n";
  assert(gv.IntVal == 9099899);
  llvm_shutdown();
  delete EE;
  return 0;
}
```